# Making a directory ssl and all other pages/dirs not ssl

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

Fairly simple request.. I'd like to use mod_rewrite on apache to make a directory redirect to ssl on my website, and make it so that it 'breaks out' of ssl when you navigate outside of that directory. Getting into https is easy enough using the following:

```
# Make gift-cards https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} gift-cards 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/staging/$1 [R,L,C]

# Make all other pages normal
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !gift-cards 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/staging/$1 [R,L]
```

But breaking out proves to be a bit of a problem, I'm not really sure what's going on.. my make all other pages normal rule doesn't seem to work for some reason (and I get a funny 'Found' message if I don't use C to chain the two together).

Thanks!

Comment: Please note that gift-cards isn't a real directory on the file system, later on it gets re-written to index.php etc.. as I'm using this with wordpress. The wordpress rules are below these ones, and these are the first. As these rules use the L modifier, they are the last run if they match.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this by getting to the root of the problem and using wordpress SSL plugin which does it all for me.

I think I'd probably be barking up the wrong tree using this method as then I'd have to worry about all the resources getting loaded over http etc..